# Web Scraping images (Beautiful Soup) into a directory with one function, trying to append those images into a list in another function, struggling

Tags: python, arraylist, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, praw

> So I am trying to add each image from each reddit post that I extract and store in a directory with Beautiful soup into my list "post_imgs" This is only part of my program, not the complete thing. I'm just not sure how I do this since my web scraping function and appending list function are separate. The two functions need to be separate for my program to work. This is for a Bot i'm working on as a personal project.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import praw

img_dir = 'pics'

def get_image(img_url):
    if not os.path.exists(img_dir):
        os.makedirs(img_dir)

    url = img_url
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = bs(data, 'lxml')

    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

    os.chdir(img_dir)
    x = 0

    for image in image_tags:
        try:
            url = image['src']
            source = requests.get(url)
            if source.status_code == 200:
                img_file = img_dir + str(x) + '.jpg'
                with open(img_file, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
                    f.close()
                    x += 1
                    return img_file #is this right?
        except:
            pass
    return ''

def appending_lists(subreddit_info):
    post_links = []
    post_titles = []
    post_ids = []
    post_imgs = []

    for submission in subreddit_info.new(limit=5):
        if not already_tweeted(submission.id):
            post_titles.append(submission.title)
            post_links.append(submission.shortlink)
            post_ids.append(submission.id)
            post_imgs = os.listdir(get_image(submission.shortlink)) #this is where my problem is
            #How do I add the image file into this list.

    return post_links, post_titles, post_ids, post_imgs
```

> If you are confused about the "submission.id,submission.title" etc. stuff, It just means that I am extracting, using praw, the ID and title of the Reddit posts.

Here is the updated version

```
def get_image(img_url):
    url = img_url
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = bs(data, 'lxml')

    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

    os.chdir(img_dir)
    x = 0
    mylist = []
    for image in image_tags:
        try:
            url = image['src']
            source = requests.get(url, stream = True)
            if source.status_code == 200:
                img_file = img_dir + str(x) + '.jpg'
                with open(img_file, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
                    mylist.append(img_file)
                    f.close()
                    x += 1
                    return img_file
        except:
            mylist.append(None)
    return mylist

def appending_lists(subreddit_info):
    post_links = []
    post_titles = []
    post_ids = []
    post_imgs = []

    for submission in subreddit_info.new(limit=5):
        if not already_tweeted(submission.id):
            post_titles.append(submission.title)
            post_links.append(submission.shortlink)
            post_ids.append(submission.id)
            post_imgs = get_image(submission.shortlink).copy() #this is where my problem is
            #How do I add the image file into this list.

    return post_links, post_titles, post_ids, post_imgs
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost! You can either create a list of the URLs in your first function and return the list to use in the second function, or, you can open the file in your second function that you've just written to and take the information directly from there.

```
with open(img_file, 'r') as file:
#Read the file then perform list appending
```

Comment: Hi there. So I updated my code. Was this what you meant? Still getting errors in my program, not sure why

Comment: Also with your 2nd option, how would I go about calling the get_image function before opening the file and appending the contents.